# Not getting any decimals Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, math, decimal

Im getting pretty desperate with this. It should be easy but somehow Im doing something wrong.

I have this code to display the result of a well know physics equation, however I don't seem to get the decimals on the answer. If the answer is 2.5 i get 2.00 if it is 0.2 I get 0.00. Can someone picture out why?

On the .h file:

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController {

    float result;   
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *VariableResult;
```

On the .m file:

```
    if ([VariableSelected.text isEqual: @"Position"]) {
    result = [VelocityVariable.text intValue] * [AccelerationVariable.text intValue] *   [TimeVariable.text intValue];
    VariableResult.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2f", result];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Integer multiplied by integer, remains an Integer. You should get the `floatValue` instead of the `intValue`, ie.

```
result = [VelocityVariable.text floatValue] 
       * [AccelerationVariable.text floatValue] 
       * [TimeVariable.text floatValue];
```

You may also consider using a [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/index.html)

```
NSNumberFormatter* nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
nf.positiveFormat = @"0.##";
VariableResult.text = [nf stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:result]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are multiplying `int` value that's why you are getting this result, replace `intValue` with `floatValue` as shown below

```
if ([VariableSelected.text isEqual: @"Position"]) 
{
    result = [VelocityVariable.text floatValue] * [AccelerationVariable.text floatValue] * [TimeVariable.text floatValue];
    VariableResult.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2f", result];
}
```

Comment: don't worry, sometimes it happens :)